# how to use binary file to create a cluster in bare metal

Tags: kubernetes

Already to download the all binary about kubernetes,

the directory:

```
~/vagrant/kubernetes/server/kubernetes/server/bin$ ls
federated-apiserver                 kubelet
hyperkube                           kubemark
kube-apiserver                      kube-proxy
kube-apiserver.docker_tag           kube-proxy.docker_tag
kube-apiserver.tar                  kube-proxy.tar
kube-controller-manager             kube-scheduler
kube-controller-manager.docker_tag  kube-scheduler.docker_tag
kube-controller-manager.tar         kube-scheduler.tar
kubectl
```

Can use these binary directly to create a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but unfortunately it is a non-trivial task to start with plain binaries and end up with a fully functional cluster.

To create a cluster, I'd recommend following one of the many supported [solutions](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/). If you want to create a cluster without using one of the existing scripts, you can follow the [Creating a Custom Cluster from Scratch](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/) guide.

Comment: It seems easier to clone and complie the source code .

Comment: You can use a release tarball with most of the cluster creation solutions to build a cluster at a known stable point (instead of from HEAD) since the cluster creation scripts are bundled in the release archive.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the tar.gz(flannel\etcd\kubernetes) and modified download-release.sh by changing curl to tar local files directly.Then i run kube-up.sh and created a cluster with downloaded files.